# Error occur After Updating Android Support Library & Android Support Repository

Tags: android, sdk

Today I update
 **Android Support Library** and
 **Android Support Repository**.

Now when I create a new project following error occur.

```
[2015-01-05 18:45:15 - CardLayout] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-01-05 18:45:15 - CardLayout] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-01-05 18:45:15 - CardLayout] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-01-05 18:45:15 - CardLayout] Versions found are:
[2015-01-05 18:45:15 - CardLayout] Path: D:\WorkingProjects\CardLayout\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-05 18:45:15 - CardLayout]  Length: 995624
[2015-01-05 18:45:15 - CardLayout]  SHA-1: 3e4e879d0b3dc11f2feb3f55e77e3b5bd82c4a28
[2015-01-05 18:45:15 - CardLayout] Path: D:\WorkingProjects\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-05 18:45:15 - CardLayout]  Length: 995386
[2015-01-05 18:45:15 - CardLayout]  SHA-1: a13f8fe2c278737e2f0b6fcf00f6b2ae4034aacf
[2015-01-05 18:45:15 - CardLayout] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

what can I do?

Comment: This happened once with my project. I had a library project included in my app which where referencing both the android-support-v4.jar and from different platforms. Maybe this applies to you as well?

Comment: yes, but now what to do?

Comment: @clash u solved this Issue?

Comment: I did, check my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Two different versions of the android-support-v4.jar are conflicting.

If you are still using eclipse do:

1. For each project:

   1. Right-click your project
   2. Click "Android Tools" -> "Add Support Library..."
2. Clean
3. Build
4. Run

Comment: Still same error... Now I solved this by extends Activity instead of ActionBarActivity..